# Location of server affects the speed of page loading?

Tags: web-application, webserver, web-service, web-hosting

i live in a country but i make a website for another country's users. The web hosting company has server in both of the countries. So where should i buy?

Does it affects where the server is depending on the user's country or it does not affects at all?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with information security.

Comment: belongs on [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while this is totally off topic on this site. you want your webserver to be as close to the user as possible. the latency of the network is based on where the server is. closer server means less network hops which means less latency.